# Installing Windows 7 using Serva fails with error 3

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-installation, pxe, tftp

I have an old Toshiba laptop which does not have CD Rom and also it does not support boot from USB. I want to install Windows 7 in it. After some searching, i came to know that i can install it using Serva software. I connected my New Laptop with Old Toshiba laptop using crossover cable and made all the configuration of Serva mentioned in a website.

The problem is that when i network/ PXE boot my Toshiba laptop, it initially detects installation from network like Windows 7 installation folder. But as soon as i click start the installation by hitting Enter, it loads the ServaBoot.wim file and after that screen of Toshiba Laptop goes black.

I checked the logs in the New Laptop where Serva was actually running, it is giving an error statement triggered many times:

```
[10/16 02:00:25.487] TFTP Err: File <\Boot\Fonts\wgl4_boot.ttf> : error 3 in CreateFile; The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I am unable to solve this error as i am not too much experienced about TFTP or PXE/ Network Booting. I have made unsuccessful attempts for the solution of the problem so far are as under:

1. Installed Serva again but this time i installed its 32 bit version
2. Tried to run it in router environment and reconfigured for router environment
3. Tried to change permissions of the shared folder "WIA_WDS" to everyone with all permission
4. Copied Windows 7 setup files again

Nothing of the solutions worked for me. I will be thankful if any expert here will help me. I will post log file if anyone wants to have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you mention (a missing font) is not related to your problem. 
Try to see if you have the correct video and NIC drivers and if the access to the offered shared files is also correct.

Comment: I have the same error, but the font file seems to be there.